# Get created table name

Tags: database, postgresql, event-triggers

I'm trying to create a `event trigger`, executed whenever a **table is created**.
When this happens I would like to insert into a table ( which has 2 columns **`id`** and **`tablename`** ) the name of the table created. Reading the docs I'm not able to find how can i get the table name.

So far I have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_layer()
RETURNS event_trigger
AS $$
    DECLARE r RECORD;
    BEGIN
            RAISE NOTICE 'event for % ', tg_tag;
            -- I would like to execute this
            --EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO "public.Layers"(name) VALUES(' || tableNameHere || ')') INTO result;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER insert_layer_event ON ddl_command_start 
WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_layer();
```

Comment: For the trigger on `ddl_command_end` you can use the [`pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html): `RAISE INFO 'Table: %', (pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()).object_identity;`

Comment: Thank you very much!! If you write an answer I'll accept! =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to retrieve some additional information, use `on ddl_command_end` trigger instead of `on ddl_command_start`. In the function calling such trigger you can use [`pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands function`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_layer()
RETURNS event_trigger
AS $$
    DECLARE r RECORD;
    BEGIN
            RAISE NOTICE 'event for % ', tg_tag;
            -- I would like to execute this
            r := pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands(); 
            INSERT INTO public."Layers"(name) VALUES(r.object_identity);
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Pay attention to the code changes:

1) You do not need to use `EXECUTE`
2) `"public.Layers"` means the table with the name exactly `"public.Layers"` in the current schema, not the table `Layers` in the schema `public`.