# Is there any possible way in Postgres to list and store newly created table automatically?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, ddl, information-schema

Context :
I am keeping one counter table to store max counters of all the tables in the public schema. (Which are updating automatically with trigger or functions upon updating main table)
But if someone created a new table in DB and forgot to add an entry in counter table, then mismatch occurring.

I need to overcome this problem. Is there any library or way to add newly created table automatically?

Research :
I have gone through this one : [Is there any way to automatically create a trigger on creation of new table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522538/is-there-any-way-to-automatically-create-a-trigger-on-creation-of-new-table-in-m)
But haven't found anything useful.

I am thinking of creating trigger, like after performing any inset in information_schema.tables, will copy that table name and store in counter table with 0 as counter value

~Soham

Comment: You can use an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-EVENT-TRIGGER) (which could also handle dropping of tables), see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39936923/get-created-table-name)

Comment: Ok, wait will try and update to you! :thumbsup: